# Yii2-curl oAuth2 with zoho

Tags: url, yii2, uri, yii2-advanced-app, zoho

I am working on `Yii2`. I have a `URL` which on hitting a browser is redirected to my redirect `URI`.

**URL**

```
https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=ZohoBugTracker.projects.ALL,ZohoBugTracker.bugs.ALL&client_id=1000&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://11.111.111.111:7000/api/oauth/zoho_auth
```

When I hit the above URL it will redirect to my redirect URI while giving a code

**Redirect URI**

After hitting the above URL the redirect URI is `http://11.111.111.111:7000/api/oauth/zoho_auth?code=1000&location=us&accounts-server=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.zoho.com`

**Redirect URI Response**

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://11.111.111.111:7000/api/oauth/zoho_auth?code=1000&location=us&accounts-server=https:%2F%2Faccounts.zoho.com'."}

How to get the `code` from the above response?

**Update 1**

As per suggestion given. I tried to send a `GET` request using [linslin](https://github.com/linslin/Yii2-Curl). Below is my code

```
 public static function authToken()
{

    $curl = new curl\Curl();
    $response = $curl->setGetParams([
        'scope' => 'ZohoBugTracker.projects.ALL,ZohoBugTracker.bugs.ALL',
        'client_id' => '1000',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'access_type' => 'offline',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://11.111.111.111:7000/api/oauth/zoho_auth',
    ])
        ->get('https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth');

    echo $response;
    exit();
}
```

And then called this function inside a function through which I am actually creating bugs using zoho API

Testing my `API` via `POSTMAN`

> http://localhost:225/inventory-web/api/web/v1/installation/email?ref_no=28373340485858U&customer_id=37030315933&site_snap_name=28373340485858U_1530958224_site_9.jpg&flag=1

My `email` function is written inside a API controller. So, it will first hit the `issueSetup($param1,$param2)`

```
public function actionEmail()
{
    .
    .
    .
    .

     Installations::setupEmail($param1, $param2, $param3);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The above function `setupEmail($param1,$param2,$param3)` is inside my controller.

```
 public static function setupEmail($ref_no, $customer_id, $install_id)
 {
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
      list(params.....)= Installations::issueSetup($param1,$param2);
     .
     .
     .
     .      
  }
```

**issuSetup funciton**

```
public static function issueSetup($param1,$param2)
{
     .
     .
     .
     .
    $token = Installations::authToken();

    exit();
    .
    .
    .
    . 
}
```

After hitting the `API` the I am getting no response in POSTMAN just the empty window

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you handle issuing this request?

Comment: i dont get it, how are you hitting the initial url are you opening it in the browser or send a curl request? as typing the above url inthe browser will ask you to enter the credentials for the Zoho platform, how are you getting the response that you have pasted above

Comment: and above all have you configured the `urlManager` in your API to allow `GET` request for the current action you are redirecting to ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam for your 1st comment. For now yes I am opening it in my browser the `client_id` and `redirect_uri` are hardcoded. After opening it in my browser a call to my `web api` is made and it returns me a response with the code in it. I want that code in my application.

Comment: you should first implement the actual scenario what i understand is that zoho api sends a hit to  `redirect_uri` provided and displays th response from that url whichever api it is? is that correct?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes it's correct

Comment: you should send a curl GET request to the zoho api url with the params and then receive the response first and add the code in your question, you can use the [linslin/curl](https://github.com/linslin/Yii2-Curl) for sending the cUrl request

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I tried to access it via Postman but I got this error `Note : Javascript is disabled in your browser. Please enable the javascript to continue.`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam kindly check my `update 1`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I am still waiting

Comment: @mrateb I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working quite fine when you enable SSL and check the response code / response header to redirect to the userAuth form on Zuhu:

```
$curl = new \linslin\yii2\curl\Curl();

/** @var Curl $response */
$curl->setGetParams([
        'scope' => 'ZohoBugTracker.projects.ALL,ZohoBugTracker.bugs.ALL',
        'client_id' => '1000',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'access_type' => 'offline',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://11.111.111.111:7000/api/oauth/zoho_auth',
])->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true)
    ->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false)
    ->setOption(CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:/Ampps/apache/conf/ssl_crt/cacert.pem')
    ->get('https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth');

$responseHeaders = $curl->responseHeaders;

if ($curl->responseCode === 302 && isset($responseHeaders['Location'])) {
    header("location: ".$responseHeaders['Location']);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this to get Error

```
if ($curl->errorCode === null) {
   echo $response;
} else {

    echo '<pre>';print_r($curl->errorCode);
}
```

Comment: Yes but still empty screen

Comment: @MrFaisal. Can you try to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.
Like
  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
    curl_exec($ch);
    $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);` And check if any luck

Comment: ok before this `$response = $curl->setGetParams([
        'scope' => 'ZohoBugTracker.projects.ALL,ZohoBugTracker.bugs.ALL',
        'client_id' => '1000',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'access_type' => 'offline',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://11.111.111.111:7000/api/oauth/zoho_auth',
    ])
        ->get('https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth');` ?